# When define action for form

Tags: html, django, forms

When one needs to define action parameter of form ? Across different projects I've seen forms with action defined as `{% url app.view parameters %}` or simply `'/contact/'` but also with `action = "."` . When do we need to provide each type of action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action` is simply the URL that the form is submitted to.

Normally in Django, a form is submitted to the same URL that originally rendered it, which is why '.' is often used. If you want to submit it to a different URL, for instance in the case of a search box that is shown on every page but processed on a single page, you can hard-code the URL or use the `{% url %}` tag to reverse-lookup the value to submit to.